# Extracting Depth images of Kinect using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

Does anyone know what is the simplest way to extract the gray-level depth images of Kinect using OpenCV and C++? any source code in this field?

Answer (score 1):

if you use OpenNI SDK, you can simply point to the buffer:

```
//on setup:
xn::DepthGenerator depthGenerator;
xn::DepthMetaData depthMD;
cv::Mat depthWrapper;

//on update loop,
//after context.WaitAnyUpdateAll();
depthGenerator.GetMetaData(depthMD);
depthWrapper = cv::Mat(depthMD.YRes(), depthMD.XRes(), CV_16UC1, (void*) depthMD.Data());
```

note that `depthWrapper` is const so you need to clone it in order to manipulate it

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html) has everything you need. Can't elaborate better than this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things (apart from reading about context, depth generator and initialization of Kinect):

- Create Mat of the type CV_16U   a.
  context.WaitOneUpdateAll(depth_map);   b. Mdepth_original =
  Mat(h_depth, w_depth, CV_16U, (void*) depth_map.GetData())   c. copy
  the Mat since it will be destroyed during next read:
  Mdepth_original.copyTo(depth);
- Map depth to gray or color. Color seems like a good idea (256^3 levels) but a human eye is more sensitive to the luminance change. Even with 256 levels you can map 10,000 Kinect levels reasonably well using [histogram equalization][1] technique. A simplest way though is to loose precision and just do I(x, y) = 255.0*z(x, y)/z_range

Here is how histogram equalization is implemented in openNI2:
https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2/blob/master/Samples/Common/OniSampleUtilities.h